# ARRAYLIST JAVA/METODO BUSCAR

Tags: java

Hola buenas tengo un problema el cual el metodo buscar al ocupar variable int me deriva a obtener los datos pero tengo que realizarlo con Tipo string me he complicado bastante lo cual no puedo conseguir que me realice la consulta de marca == r.getMarca()) si me podrian ayudar con este codigo porfavor!, de ante mano muchas gracias
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
private void Buscar() {
    if (listarepuesto.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("\n --- NO HAY DATOS PARA BUSCAR!!! ---- ");
    } else {
        System.out.println("\n DIGITE MARCA PARA BUSCAR: ");
        marca = leer.next();
        resp=false;
        for (int i = 0; i < listarepuesto.size(); i++) {
            r = listarepuesto.get(i);
            if (marca == r.getMarca()) {
                resp = true;
                System.out.println("\n REPUESTO ENCONTRADO");
                System.out.println("Codigo: " + r.getCodigo());
                System.out.println("Cantidad: " + r.getCantidad());
                System.out.println("Marca: " + r.getMarca());
                System.out.println("Nombre: " + r.getNombre() + "\n");
                break;
            }
        }
        if (resp == false) {
            System.out.println("\n ---- Marca: " + marca + " marca no encontrada");
        }
    }
    menu();
}
```

}

Comment: intenta `marca.equals(r.getMarca())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para comparar Strings no uses `==`, utiliza el método `equals`

```
marca.equals(r.getMarca())
```

Comment: Hola, si y como podria quedar el codigo si marca es de scanner y getmarca almacenado el arraylist como podria quedar, saludos

Comment: seria en vez del if(marca == r.getMarca()) seria solo if(marca.equals(r.getMarca()) y todo lo demas estaria bien cierto?

Comment: @MatiasRojas exacto, [revisa](https://www.arquitecturajava.com/comparando-java-vs-equals/)